# Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am using Android studio 2.2 and I am trying to compile the sample android application given in the get started section of developer.android.com. When I build the application I get the following error.

> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I have gone through a number of threads in stackoverflow.com related to this error. I did the following as suggested in these threads, but my problem is not resolved.

### Step 1

Updated buildgrid{} section of build.gradle (application) with this:

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

### Step 2

Updated android{} section of build.gradle (module) with this:

```
 repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

I have also configured manual proxy with a proper proxy server IP and I could also test the connection successuflly to URL https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom. I have also pasted this URL in a web browser, which downloads the junit-4.12.pom successfully. What I am not able to understand is, when connection to the above URL is successful, why the build fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below repository in your build.gradle file,

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}
```

Comment: I added the above block of code to buildscript{}, allprojects {} block of Project's build.gradle file and android{} block of Module's build.gradle file. It worked fine.

Comment: Note that maven now requires https.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today.  For me it was a proxy settings issue.

I opened the file '`gradle.properties`' in my project and added the following settings. Then everything synchronized and downloaded for me.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=XX.XX.XX.XX
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80

systemProp.https.proxyHost=XX.XX.XX.XX
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```